# GA4 link_text is usually "(not set)"

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

In diving further into GA4, I've found that the value for the link_text is "(not set)" for click events. The links on my site are standardly coded with straight a tags, so I'm trying to figure out why that link text might not be coming through. Here's an example of

```
<a data-entity-substitution="canonical" data-entity-type="node" data-entity-uuid="c3c87ca2-3545-4c38-baaa-daa78c7184bd" href="/tristate/donate">Tri-State</a>
```

Is there something else I need to add in to either GA4 or Tag Manager to get the link text to always show up?

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked two clients and neither have reported link_text data for the click events.

It looks like it is not part of the official documentation. Maybe something that existed in the past and was dropped:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9216061

Comment: Yeah, now that I look more closely, it is indeed "(not set)" for all click events. It shows for file_download, but not outbound clicks. I wonder if this is something coming soon, or if there's something we can do to have that populated on outbound link?

Comment: I've created my own click tracking events. If you do that you can add whatever information you want.